# Phaser.js coordinate collisions between two layers

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

So, I have two layers, `objLayer`, and `BGLayer`

[image]

So, the wooden bridge, is non colliding, allowing the player to pass through, however, the water underneath it is colliding, and will not let the player pass through.

Assuming I cant just replace the water tile, because I need the bridge to be removable with the water still showing below, how can I Make the player cross the bridge, and the water, but not just water?

EDIT:
I'm using a tiled tileset property for collisions, as I have more than just water tiles to collide with

```js
this.BGLayer.setCollisionByProperty({ collides: true });
this.objLayer.setCollisionByProperty({ collides: true });
const debugGraphics = this.add.graphics().setAlpha(0.75);
       this.worldLayer.renderDebug(debugGraphics, {
        tileColor: null, // Color of non-colliding tiles
        collidingTileColor: new Phaser.Display.Color(243, 134, 48, 255), // Color of colliding tiles
        faceColor: new Phaser.Display.Color(40, 39, 37, 255), // Color of colliding face edges
      });
```

So I added the function in collide callback,

```js
this.physics.add.collider(this.player, this.BGLayer);
    this.physics.add.collider(this.player, this.objLayer, function () {
      let tile = this.objLayer.getTileAtWorldXY(this.player.x, this.player.y);
      if (tile != null && tile.index == 16) {
        console.log("bridge")
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    });
```

However it gives a bug if put in BGLayer, and putting it in obj layer also does nothing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can use the `processCallback` of the `collider` function ([details phaser docs](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Collider.html)).

In that function you can check, if the player is on a bridge-tile. if so the `processCallback` function should return `false` in all other cases return `true`.

```
...
this.physics.add.collider( player, water, collideCallback, processCallback, this);
...
```

The `processCallback` could look something like this:

```
function processCallback(){
    let tile = objLayer.getTileAtWorldXY(player.x, player.y);
    if ( tile && tile.index == BRIDGE_TILE_INDEX ){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

**Update:**

Example adapted to your code:

```
this.physics.add.collider(this.player, this.objLayer, function (){
        // ... you could put some code
    }, 
    function () {
        let tile = this.objLayer.getTileAtWorldXY(this.player.x, this.player.y);
        if (tile != null && tile.index == 16) {
            console.log("bridge")
            return false;
         }
         return true;
 });
```

Comment: My collider isn't like with just the water tile

Comment: This is all _pseudo code_ in my example. the **water** would have to be `BGLayer` or so. but without knowing your code I just use some placeholders to explain my point.

Comment: I edited the Q, I get the collide callback function, but I dont see how the return false ties in with process callback

Comment: @VatsaPandey sorry I, copy / pasted wrong,  it should be the `processCallback` not the `collideCallback`. I updated the answer.